# Knockout.js making text large on mouseover

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, knockout.js

[Here's my Code](http://jsfiddle.net/gQv4B/2/) 
I need to make those texts bold/larger on a mouseover event and return to normal on mouseout..  Couldn't figure out how can i do it after storming the internet and find about nothing about integrating groups with toggle events.

I'd like to specify that i'm rather new to knockout, so a little explanation with the code would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
<ul data-bind="foreach: List" style="text-align: center;" dir="rtl">
<li class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedGroups" data-bind="attr: { value: Id }, checked: $root.Selected" />
        <span data-bind="text: Value"></span>
    </label>
</li>
</ul>
<br/></br>

<p dir="rtl" style="text-align: center" >מספר המועמדים שנבחרו: <label data-bind="text:  Selected().length"></label></p>
</div>
```

Script

```
 var viewModel = {
List: ko.observableArray([ { Id: 1, Value: "מועמד ראשון" }, 
                           { Id: 2, Value: "מועמד שני" }, 
                           { Id: 3, Value: "מועמד שלישי" },
                          { Id: 4, Value: "מועמד רביעי" },
                          { Id: 5, Value: "מועמד חמישי" },
                          { Id: 6, Value: "מועמד שישי" }
                          ]),
   Selected: ko.observableArray(/*[" פה ניתן להוסיף מועמדים שנבחרו קודם לכן עם ',' בינהם*"]*/)
};

viewModel.SelectedLength = ko.computed(function() { return viewModel.Selected().length;     });

viewModel.onPush = function() {
viewModel.Selected.push();
};

viewModel.onPop = function() {
viewModel.Selected.pop();
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The css class i would like to toggle on the texts:

```
.field-onmouseover {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: xx-large;
cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; 
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `:hover` pseudo-selectors in your CSS?

Comment: Exactly! This is simply a HTML issue and has nothing to do with knockout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the css and add the pseudoclass hover

```
.checkbox span[data-bind]:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: xx-large;
    cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; 
}
```

but if you want to specifically add an event check this out http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html